# Hosting static content like images on parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, mbaas

My android mobile app needs to display static images, which i cannot bundle with my app.

Assuming parse.com as back-end.
In a table i can keep URL reference to these images.

How do i host these images in parse.com? 
Essentially i am looking for a aws s3 kind of equivalent in parse. 
I find no screen to upload this static content like images.

I could store the image in table column with type: File. 
`ParseFile.getUrl()` method exists, but the URL is not predictable - that makes it difficult to use.

Comment: Why is having an unpredictable url a problem?....If the file is associated with a user for instance, when you get the parse object for the user, you can simply convert the image row to a Parse file and then extract its url using the method you mentioned?

Comment: @JayDev > I have 100s of image names that come from a config file. If image files are in a parse.com table as a file - i will have to query the table every time to get image path. And often inside for loops - which is inefficient.

Comment: Why not store the url in the config file rather than the name that way there would be no need to get the url from each parse file

Comment: @JayDev The images files are often updated(replaced) which results in URL change in parse - and config file is already released to client  - so they won't be in synch. So either the paths have to be constant OR i determine at run time.

Comment: Sorry the fact you classified them as static images made me think they would be staying the same. In which case I'm not sure parse is what you're looking for because I don't think what you're looking for is going to be possible without a major hack

Comment: @JayDev By the way i have looked at web hosting part of Parse.com - where i can put images - unfortunately  it has an upper limit of only 500 files.